# setNativeDialogHandler to handle ie11 access Clipboard

Tags: automated-tests, internet-explorer-11, clipboard, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a test that initiates a copy to clipboard.  in ie11 that generates a dialog https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSEIT.jpg

I can't clear it.  Here is my code

```
fixture.only`Downloads`
    .page`${page.page}`
    .beforeEach(async (t) => {
        await t
            .maximizeWindow()
            .setNativeDialogHandler((type, text, url) => {
                if (type === 'confirm') { return false } return true
            })
        await page.loginAdmin()
    })
    .afterEach(async (t) => {
        await t.setNativeDialogHandler(null)
    })
```

But it won't clear the dialog.  I have also tried

```
.setNativeDialogHandler(() => true)
```

but the dialog remains and the test times out

Comment: Try the solution from the thread below: IE -> Internet Options -> Security -> Internet zone -> Custom Level -> Allow programmatic clipboard access. 
https://edumanual.pbworks.com/w/page/61242170/Clipboard%20Access%20for%20Internet%20Explorer.

Comment: thanks.  that will solve the dialog showing up.  I need then to determine how to configure IE that way.  I can snapshot a testVM configured like that for local testing... I'll have to look in to how I can get saucelabs (browser testing service) to give me an ie11 with that configuration

Comment: In this case, I suggest you wait for TestCafe to support Clipboard out of the box: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2668

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach for Clipboard interaction:

```
const overrideClipboardCopy = ClientFunction(() => {
    const execCommand = document.execCommand;

    document.execCommand = (action, ...args) => {
        if (action === 'copy') {
            //handle copy here
        }
        else
            return execCommand.call(document, ...args);
    }
});
```

See also: [Allow to use HTML5 Clipboard API in tests](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2668)